# Complete task before running loop for next member

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I have this simple and short javascript code for a website:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get().then(function(doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const data = doc.data();
            const members = data.members;

            members.forEach(el => {

              db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    const data = doc.data();

                    //some stuff

                });
              });
            })

          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
```

As you can see I need to run two Firebase Firestore tasks. It is important that first this runs `db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get().then(function(doc) {` and for each of the members this task follows `db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {` (NOTE: The second task needs the first one because of the var `el`). So my problem is that I must wait to finish the second task before the loop for the next member could go on.

And exactly this is my question: how to complete the second task before running the loop for next member?

**EDIT:**
I modified my Javascript code like this:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const data = doc.data();
        const members = data.members;

        members.reduce((chain, el) => {

          table_number++;
          const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, member_name);
          document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

            return chain.then(() =>
                db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        const data = doc.data();

                        addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);
                    });
                })
            )
        }, Promise.resolve());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});

function fillTemplate(table_name, id) {
  console.log("ID OF TABLES  " + table_name);
  return `
  <div class="noten_tabelle_permission" id="noten_tabelle_permission">
    <h1 id="member_name">${id}</h1>
    <table id="${table_name}" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Fach</th>
        <th>mündlich</th>
        <th>Klausur</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- Make content with js code -->
    </table>
  </div>
  `;
}

function addToTable(table_name, subject, mdl, klu) {

  var subject_name = getSubjectByNumber(subject);
  var short_subject = getSubjectShortByNumber(subject);

      //Zeile erstellen

      console.log("addToTable " + table_name);

      var y = document.createElement([short_subject]);
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);
      document.getElementById([table_name]).appendChild(y);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var cE = document.createElement("TD");
      var tE = document.createTextNode([subject_name]);
      cE.appendChild(tE);
      y.appendChild(cE);

      var a = document.createElement("TD");
      var b = document.createTextNode([mdl]);
      a.appendChild(b);
      y.appendChild(a);

      var c = document.createElement("TD");
      var d = document.createTextNode([klu]);
      c.appendChild(d);
      y.appendChild(c);


      document.getElementById(table_name).appendChild(y);
}
```

So the promise works. But now I have the Problem that the promise works wrong. As you can see I want to run a Firestore(Database) task for every member. So the promise should fire every new member. But the promise is going to fire first at the end.

Background knowledge: I get the members from an ArrayList from the database and for every single member I need to get specific values based on that member. When the values for the member loaded I add them to a table, which is populated for every member(as you can see) in the previous task. As I said the promise is going to fire at the end. **So the values would not be added to the specific table of the member. They are going to be added to the last table.**

**EDIT 2**:
This is the edited Code:

```
members.reduce((chain, el) => {

              db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("user_data").doc("u").get().then(function (doc) {
                const data = doc.data();
                var member_name = data.name;

                table_number++;
                const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, member_name);
                document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
              })


          return chain.then(((table_num) => {
            return db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                const data = doc.data();

                addToTable("grade_table" + table_num, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);

              });
            })
          }).bind(null, table_number))
        }, Promise.resolve());
```

So the problem here is that the task where I get the member_name runs asynchronously and the other part not. So I only can run the whole task when everything is loaded. Because as you see I need also the member_name. SO how to recode it that the task run when only everything (member_name/grades) are loaded.

Comment: I would take a look at await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` instead of `forEach` with an empty `Promise` passed as an initial value in order to process members sequentially:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const data = doc.data();
        const members = data.members;

        members.reduce((chain, el) => {
            return chain.then(() =>
                db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        //some stuff
                    });
                })
            )
        }, Promise.resolve());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

**Update #1**:

Taking into account the updated question, the data is probably added to the last table because for the time of promises resolution all reduce iterations have been finished (and therefore `table_name` variable keeps the value from the last iteration). You can solve it by `binding` `table_name` value to the callback invoked on the promise resolution:

```
members.reduce((chain, el) => {

  table_number++;
  const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id);
  document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

  return chain.then(((table_num) => {
    return db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        const data = doc.data();

        addToTable("grade_table" + table_num, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);
      });
    })
  }).bind(null, table_number))
}, Promise.resolve());
```

---

**Update #2**:
In order to run multiple asynchronous operations subsequently within a single reduce iteration try to chain them using `then` method of a Promise:

```
members.reduce((chain, el) => {

  return chain
    .then(() => db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("user_data").doc("u").get())
    .then(doc => {
      const data = doc.data();
      var member_name = data.name;

      table_number++;
      const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, member_name);
      document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
      return table_number;
    })
    .then(table_num => {
      return db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          const data = doc.data();

          addToTable("grade_table" + table_num, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);

        });
      })
    })

}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit and declare to me why it does not work, please?

Comment: @FilipDegenhart I have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @FilipDegenhart My pleasure.

Comment: Sorry if I annoy you, but can you please have a final look at my Edit 2, because I really want to figure out how all this works. Thanks :)

Comment: @FilipDegenhart Sorry, I am not sure how to extract `member_name` unfortunately, since I don't know much about the data structure you have. However, I assume that it can be found in `el` (second parameter of the callback passed to `reduce`). If `el` is an object that represents a member, it's likely that it contains information such as a member name.

Comment: Hey antonku, can you please have a look at the update of my edit2 and help me out of this?

Comment: Hi @FilipDegenhart, thanks for the added details. I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the fast update and understanding helps. Thanks:)

Comment: @FilipDegenhart No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get()
.then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const data = doc.data();
            const members = data.members;

            const promises = []

            members.forEach(el => {
              const usersPromise = db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get();
              promises.push(usersPromise);
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);

          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
            throw new Error("No such document!");
          }
})
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data();
                    //some stuff
        });
    });     
})  
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Error", error);
});
```

The `results` returned when the single Promise returned by `Promise.all(promises)` resolves is an array with all the results of the promises, **in the same order you pushed the promises in the `promises` array**.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my EDIT? It fires at the wrong time.

Comment: I think you should ask that to the SO member who wrote the other answer, based on `members.reduce()`, i.e. antonku. My answer is based on `Promise.all()`.